# Ограничения MSSQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql

У меня вопрос как создать ограничения повторяющихся значений полей,не являющихся ключевыми?
поля:
-номер (ключевое, автоинкремент)
-год
-дисциплина
-курс
-поток
и т.д

я хочу чтоб комбинация год+дисциплина+курс+поток была уникальна, но при этом,что б ключевым полем так же осталось поле номер! (конечно можно эти поля сделать ключевыми, но мне в дальнейшем надо работать именно с полем номер, и оно должно быть ключевым).

Подскажите как это сделать?(с триггерами запутался.....с ограничениями не могу сделать, чтоб была уникальность всех этих полей)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

декларативное ограничение UNIQUE решает проблему:

```
alter table имя_таблицы
add constraint uydcp
unique(год,дисциплина,курс,поток)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает... :))))

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам ответили правильно. Стоит отметить вопрос как приняты.

Comment: Ок))......

Answer (score 1):

Добавить уникальный индекс по этим полям: год+дисциплина+курс+поток.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
IX_Table ON [Table] (Год,
    Дисциплина,     Курс,   Поток   )  
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table SET (LOCK_ESCALATION= TABLE)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)), я сделал немного не так....работает.....
писало:
dbo не является известным параметром ALTER TABLE, я попробовал
написать
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table SET (LOCK_ESCALATION= [имя_базы].dbo.имя_таблицы)...и без dbo (просто таблицу)....но всёравно выругивалось...
Открыл таблицу-Индексы-создать новый, и в "добавить" выбрал необходимые поля
Спасибо...